# Tizen UI - E17 & EVAS in Enlightenment Foundation Library

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, tizen

I understand that Tizen uses EFL & it contains a E17(Window Manager) for X11 & a module called EVAS(is a Canvas layer,where we can create & manipulate EVAS objects & display them)

**My questions are**

- What does E17 does other than being a window manager in Tizen ?
- Is EVAS is just a Canvas library, I mean how does it display on Screen ,
  Does it USes  EGL/OPENGL internally ?
- The documentation of tizen says , E17 Supports both Software & hardware 
  rendering(OpenGL based) , How does it handle Software rendering , does it 
  Uses X11 Compositor for Software rendering, if not how is software rendering is done.?

Answer (score 4):

> What does E17 does other than being a window manager in Tizen ?

Nothing else. It's the Window Manager.

> Is EVAS is just a Canvas library, I mean how does it display on Screen , Does it USes EGL/OPENGL internally ?

EVAS provides an abstraction between the low level system and a higher level program. EVAS can be compiled with multiple backends. Those backends can be a software rasterizer or something system dependent.

> The documentation of tizen says , E17 Supports both Software & hardware rendering(OpenGL based). How does it handle Software rendering

It uses EVAS which will use the rendering backend that matches the available resources on the system that provide the best performance and/or quality.

> does it Uses X11 Compositor for Software rendering

X11 compositing is something completely different than rendering. Compositing makes things like alpha blended windows, window transition animations and such possible. Most X11 compositors use OpenGL and hardware acceleration to do their job.

X11 of course also provides graphics primitives to render pictures with. There are the X core drawing operations, and the Render extensions. Those can be HW accelerated by the graphics driver or fall back to an internal software implementation depending on the system.

> if not how is software rendering is done?

The EFL of which EVAS is part of contain a very performance software raster operations libraries (the Enlightenment main developer's nickname is 'Rasterman' for a reason ;) ). If EVAS detects that there is insufficient HW support it falls back to this software rasterizer.

Comment: Who does the Actual Composition in the case of Tizen, Is it EVAS or E17, as per answer it seems like EVAS does the actual composition & E17 is just merely managing or acting as a window manager., So if EVAS is doing the composition is it using some X11 Compositor ? , When i browsed the code of E17 in Tizen repo., I see that E17 uses EGL Calls , does it needs any extra render extension as well other than EGL lib ?

Comment: E17 does the composition (it is the actual X11 client), EVAS is "just" some library that provides graphics functions. And as it happens the EVAS functions can be used to implement a compositor. So E17 does the composition, by using functions from EVAS. The EGL calls are probably part of the EVAS Wayland port, as EGL is not used in X11 (except for compatibility applications like emulators). Anyway, E17+EVAS **is** the (X11) compositor. X11 itself doesn't contain a compositor it just provides a protocol that allows the implementation of compositors. Composition is not mandatory in X11.

Comment: @GeekPanther: EVAS can use whatever rendering method it sees fit to draw the actual composition. X11 doesn't force the use of a particular drawing API to implement a compositor as long as the final result is somehow put on the screen through X11. However it makes sense to use APIs that allow server side rendering, like OpenGL or XRender. EVAS can use either.